# Django Ignoring updates to urls.py

Tags: django, python-3.5, django-urls

The urls.py file  In My Dango Project Is being Ignored; for Example I Tried Commenting Out The Admin Urls From the Project, And I Could Still Use The Admin. I tried Adding A Name Space, And Django Says It Doesn't Exist.

mysite/urls.py:

```py
    """mysite URL Configuration

    The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information, please see:
        https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/
    Examples:
    Function views
        1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
        2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
    Class-based views
        1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
        2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
    Including another URLconf
        1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
        2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
    """
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path,include
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    from . import settings

    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('',include("Wallet.urls"),
        path('',include("django.contrib.auth.urls"))
    ] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root='/home/dh_hemuuv/minicoin.fztl.com/static')
```

Wallet/urls.py:

```py
from django.urls import path
from .views import signup,viewWallet,transfer,userpage,collectgift

urlpatterns = [
    path("signup/",signup,name="signup"),
    path("",viewWallet,name="home"),
    path("transfer/",transfer,name="transfer"),
    path("account/<str:username>/",userpage),
    path("collectgift/<int:id>/",collectgift,name="colgift"),
]
```

Please Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oops I Found My Problem I found a Pesky `__pycache__` Folder Deleteing Solved my problems